# how to fix cors issue in api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a javascript SDK from AWS Gateway to make calls to my api. I have tried adding multiple headers which i came across the documentation and web. But i couldn't find the solution. I am authenticating user using facebook and i have the api working in python.

```
AWS.config.region = region';
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId ,
            Logins: {
                'graph.facebook.com':fbTokenId

            }
        });
 AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
            var identityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
            var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
            var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
            var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
            apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
                                                        accessKey: accessKeyId,
                                                        secretKey: secretAccessKey,
                                                        sessionToken: sessionToken,
                                                        //region: region
                                                    });
apigClient.rootGet({},{},{})
                .then(function(result){
                  // Add success callback code here.
                 console.log("result : ");
                 console.log(result);
                }).catch( function(result){
                  // Add error callback code here.
                console.log(result);
                });
```

This is the error i am seeing in console.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://####.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/####/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was a mismatch of region. Please make the region is right.

**As per Docs:**
If you specify the general endpoint (elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com), Amazon EMR directs your request to an endpoint in the default region. For accounts created on or after March 8, 2013, the default region is us-west-2; for older accounts, the default region is us-east-1.